# Android SQLite ORDER BY query won't process

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ok, so I have a database of an accounting app, which contains the information of various items purchased.

Said database looks like this:

[Unsorted SQLite database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2PZf.png)

Upon running the query `SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY totalPrice DESC;` in SQLite Studio 3.1.1, the db sorts itself cleanly to this:

[Updated database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeZT6.png)

However, trying to run `mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY totalPrice DESC;")` via the Java SQLite library results in nothing. The db isn't sorted at all. I've also tried running `mDatabase.query("items", null, null, null, null, null, "totalPrice DESC;");`

I'm at a complete loss as to what to do for this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by *db isn't sorted at all.*?

Comment: The command doesn't seem to go through, the database remains the same as the top picture.

Comment: `Order by` *don't* sort the database. They only sort the resultset of the query.

Answer (score 2):

> The command doesn't seem to go through, the database remains the same as the top picture.

A `SELECT` statement does not change the database. It returns data from the database. The `Cursor` that you get back from `rawQuery()` or `query()` will have the rows in its result set sorted per the `ORDER BY` clause. The actual database, though, will remain untouched.